# Google Sheets no menu iPad

Tags: ipad

My GoogleSheets app on a late-model iPad Pro looks like this:

[image: this]

I would like to select all rows and columns of this data (700+ columns wide) and create a line graph that shows these sunrise times over time.  (I am not certain Sheets will actually graph these times like I want, but that's my goal.)

The issue I'm addressing here is that Google Sheets on this iPad seems to have no option for menus, and so everything I try to do is a headache.... and, lacking a menu, some things (like insert graph) are not possible.

How can I cause that menu to appear?  "Settings" in Sheets is extremely limited, no help there.  I've found articles that talk about long-pressing the screen and exiting Full screen mode (long-pressing the screen here simply selects a cell), and I've found many articles that talk about keystroke combinations (not all agree regarding what to press), but I lack a keyboard... So for me, for now, Google Sheets is like the little engine that won't try.

What might I be missing?